# Error using EtherJS: this.provider.getTransactionCount is not a function

Tags: javascript, ethereum, ether

I'm trying to use Ether.js in React-Native environment to send ether. I followed the example on the Etherjs guide.

This is my code:

```
let privateKey = 'walletPrivateKey';
    let destinationAddress = '0xa43cBF460670deA2AcC7642bBF71DBe867dB2e06';
    var wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey,['rinkeby','rinkebyKeyAPI']);
    console.log('Address: ' + wallet.address);
    console.log(wallet);

    var transaction = {
      gasLimit: 1000000,
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.bigNumberify("20000000000"),
      to: "0xa43cBF460670deA2AcC7642bBF71DBe867dB2e06",
      data: "0x",
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.000666"),
    };

    let sendTransactionPromise = wallet.sendTransaction(transaction);
    sendTransactionPromise.then(function(transactionHash) {
      console.log(transactionHash);
    });
```

When I throw this function i will get the following error:

> this.provider.getTransactionCount is not a function

How I could solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue was related to the provider settings. With this line everything works fine:

```
wallet.provider = new ethers.providers.InfuraProvider('rinkeby','rinkebyKeyAPI');
```